# I can't connect the android library

Tags: android, github

how do I connect this library correctly? https://github.com/FireZenk/AudioWaves .the compile() method is outdated, and if you replace it with implementation, it does not work.

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ImageWithCamera'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [org.firezenk:audiowaves:1.1@aar] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

[image]

Comment: [Stack Overflow (in Russian)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your build.gradle in poject level put this

```
repositories {
        maven { url 'https://github.com/FireZenk/maven-repo/raw/master/'}
}
```